# Como hacer estos metodos en POO JAVA

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, javafx, java-ee

Estoy realizando este pequeño ejercicio pero me confunde un poco los requisitos

Estos dos métodos debo realizaros:

**Agregar un método vender, no retorna nada, recibe la cantidad de productos vendidos y modifica los atributos respectivos: disminuye productosActuales, incrementa productosVendidos**

**Agregar un método devolver, no retorna nada, recibe la cantidad de productos vendidos y modifica los atributos respectivos: incrementa productosActuales, disminuye productosVendidos, incrementa productosDevueltos**

Clase Item

```
public class Item {

private String nombre;
private int productosactuales;
private int productosdevueltos;
private int productosvendidos;

public void imprimir(){
    
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println("PRODUCTOS");
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosactuales);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosdevueltos);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosvendidos);
}

public void vender(int cantidad){
    
    
}

public void devolver(int cantidad){
    
}
```

}

Como puedo realizar el metodo vender y devolver entiendo que son de tipo Void porque no retorna ningún valor en ambos casos ? No requiero que me lo resuelvan mas bien prefiero una explicación detallada.

La clase TestItem se hacerla, pero estos dos metodos es lo unico que me falta

Comment: En realidad parece algo simple ¿nos mostrarías por favor qué has intentado?

Comment: A decir verdad es lo que llevo soy nuevo en esto, pero me confunde esos métodos a la hora de agregar o incrementar

Comment: Para eso debes usar los operadores de incremento y decremento (*++ y --*) te recomiendo empezar a buscar sobre ellos

Comment: Los métodos no retornan nada por que solo modifican el estado del objeto, podrías optar por mostrar un mensaje el estilo 'venta registrada' o 'devolución aceptada'. La idea es sumar y/o restar lo que te pasan como parámetro a los campos correspondientes. Detalle: *no se puede vender más de lo que se tiene*.

Comment: La explicacion detalla que estas pidiendo, esta en el enunciado de tu ejercicio. no se puede agregar mucho mas.. el metodo vender, vende... entonces hay menos productos actuales, y mas productos vendidos...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Según el enunciado, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```java
public class Item {

private String nombre;
private int productosactuales;
private int productosdevueltos;
private int productosvendidos;

public void imprimir(){
    
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println("PRODUCTOS");
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosactuales);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosdevueltos);
    System.out.println("Porductos actuales: " + productosvendidos);
}

public void vender(int cantidad){  
   productosactuales = productosactuales - cantidad; // disminuye productosActuales
   productosvendidos = productosvendidos + cantidad; // incrementa productosVendidos


}

public void devolver(int cantidad){
    productosactuales = productosactuales + cantidad; // incrementa productosActuales
    productosvendidos = productosvendidos - cantidad; // disminuye productosVendidos
    productosDevueltos = productosDevueltos + cantidad; // incrementa productosDevueltos
}
```

Si bien estos métodos siguen estrictamente al enunciado, en una aplicación real, deberías tener ciertas validaciones para asegurar la integridad del estado del objeto. Por ejemplo no vender más productos de los que tienes disponibles.

En cuanto a la explicación detallada, no hay mucho por decir, siguiendo el enunciado, cuando se llama al método `vender(cantidad)` lo que sucede es que las propiedades:

```java
private int productosactuales;
private int productosvendidos;
```

Van a ser modificadas en base al parámetro `cantidad`, lo que representaria una venta de N productos, que en el mundo real harian que la cantidad de productos acutales disminuya (debido a que los vendiste) y que la cuenta que llevas de productos vendidos suba.

Cuando se llama al método `devolver(cantidad)` pasa lo contrario que en vender, ya que se incrementa los productos actuales (te devolvieron los productos), se disminuye la cuenta de productos vendidos y aumenta la cuenta que se lleva de productos devueltos.